# matlab pol2cart from a txt file and plot

Tags: matlab, points

I have a .txt file with cylindrical coordinates, `theta`, `x` (would be rho in matlab) and `z`, all in numbers. I am trying to convert them into cartesian coordinates and then plot them (mesh or surf). I imported the txt file and i have now 3 variables `theta,x,z.` I used the command `[x,y,z] = pol2cart (theta, x, z)` but the result is a one column only.

Where I am wrong?

The datas are in columns separated by a blank space:

```
10.2837 -99.975 36.8826
10.2837 -99.963 36.8826
10.2837 -99.95  36.8826
10.2837 -99.938 36.8826
```

Comment: Can you show us what your variables `theta`, `x` and `z` look like, as well as the output of `pol2cart`? Also, it's not a good idea to overwrite your variable `x`. Either call the input to the function `rho`, or the output something else other than `x`.

Comment: I changed the variables as you suggested. Due to the high number of points i wasn't able to see exactly what was the output of matlab. I picked only 3 points and this is the risult: <br/>   [x,y,z] = pol2cart (theta, rho, z)

x =

   65.3091
   65.3012
   65.2927


y =

   75.6950
   75.6859
   75.6760


z =

   36.8826
   36.8826
   36.8826    ...i am not able to format correctly the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you get a "one column only" output when you specify three output variables. Do you get an error message?

Have you managed to get your data into a matrix? (As a Matlab variable, not a text-file with spaces?) If so, try:

```
data_mat = [10.2837 -99.975 36.8826
            10.2837 -99.963 36.8826
            10.2837 -99.95  36.8826
            10.2837 -99.938 36.8826];

%% Assuming this order is correct:
theta = data_mat(:,1);
rho = data_mat(:,2);
zz = data_mat(:,3);

[x, y, z] = pol2cart(theta, rho, zz);
```

Also, remember to transform your angles into radians.

Comment: You are right! as i wrote in the previous comment the output was correct, but i didn't see all the output. Anyway i'll try your suggestion.